# Generate ActiveRecord includes hash from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've a schema like this:

`user` has_many `post_values` belongs_to `author` has_many `addresses`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_values
end

class PostValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :author
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_values
  has_many :addresses
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end
```

*This schema it's just an example and does not reflect a real case.*

Now I have a string like this: `post_values_author_addresses`.

Exists a library or a gem or a method inside the Rails lib that given that string return me the associations hash: `{post_values: {author: :addresses}}`?

I know that Ransack do something similar with its scopes...

I need a method like this:

```
User.get_associations(:post_values_author_addresses) => {post_values: {author: :addresses}}
```

I hope I was clear...

Comment: This does not make sense to me shouldn't the hash then be `{user: [:post_values,:author, :addresses]}` because right now it looks like the Hash you want means that a `User` has_many :post_values and a `PostValue` belongs_to :author and an `Author` has_many :addresses. Is that your schema the question is very unclear. When I read it it read it as a `User` has_many :post_values and a `User` belongs_to :author and a `User` has_many :addresses. Also can you explain why this is functionally necessary it might help us solve it for you

Comment: @engineersmnky  edited the question...

Comment: This would require some parsing logic. Do you have control over the string you get (like `post_values_author_addresses`)? Could you change it to `post_values__author__addresses`? So that every double-underscore is considered a separator of the relation names. Also, as hinted by @engineersmnky's comment, this parsing would be difficult if you want several associations "at the same level", like `post_values: {:user, author: :addresses}`. How would you write the string matching these associations hash?

Comment: The string should have only one underscore.

Comment: @Pioz what happens when chained names overlap? Say for example `User` has_one :plan and `User` has_many :plan_fields and `Plan` has_many :fields then what happens with something like `:plan_fields` should it be `:plan_fields` or `{plan: :fields}` this usage just seems very fragile and We still do not have an example of a viable use case

Comment: You right, may be this method can support two underscore for disambiguation...

Comment: The two underscores would make parsing easier as it would allow for splitting the original and then looping

Answer (score 0):

I would consider adding a 'has_one_through...' association to the `PostValue` class.

```
has_many :addresses, :through => :author
```

And the reverse for `Addresses`

```
has_many :PostValues, :through => :author
```

You may need the *inverse_of* option to tie things together, though if your naming is conventional you might be fine.

This page describes its use: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Then you might be able to use `PostValue.reflect_on_all_associations` to find the association that matches your string. I have not tried with `:through` associations, but there is a good chance you'll find what you need in the *name* attribute. Something like:

```
PostValue.reflect_on_all_associations.select {|a| a.name == my_string}
```

Disclaimer: I have used these things independently, but never tried them together. So if it fails to work, let me know and I can try and update my answer appropriately.